# android keyboard doesn't pop in on calling focus on sencha text field

Tags: android, extjs, keyboard, sencha-touch, focus

my sencha application runs on web view of android..

1. on click of a button, I load a custom component (container with some components and text field one of them) and I call the focus() method on the text field. I get the cursor in the text field, but the android keyboard doesn't come up.
2. I had placed a button in the custom component, on click of the button I moved the focus again to the text field, this time the cursor comes for a moment and goes away. Why is the cursor not staying there ?

what ever the case, by using focus() i get the cursor in the field, but the android keyboard doesn't pop in.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u add keyboard support in ur avd

Comment: Are you using keyup event in Sencha Touch?

Comment: I am also facing this issue and would love an answer for this, if anyone has found one. I've spent a lot of time trying to get the keyboard to show programmatically. Of course, as soon as I tap the input field physically, the keyboard comes up.

Comment: Consider adding a code segment. It's difficult to point out your possible errors if we don't know what mistake you may have made in the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

This code will force the keyboard to show.

```
InputMethodManager inputMgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService("A Context".INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMgr.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);
```

"A Context" could be "this" depending on where you are calling the code.